# How to access local web service from a page using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I want to learn that.Is it possible ?

I have a button on www.testwebsite.com/test.aspx.Can I access a web service on my IIS when click button ?

Answer (score 0):

[I Think this might help you.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22760/Calling-Web-Service-using-ASP-NET) It explains how to add it and call it when clicking an ImageButton.

useful piece of code for you I think:

```
// 1) Get all the published applications list by calling GetApplicationsByCredentialsEx 
//    web service.
// 2) create an ImageButton for each application
// 3) Create Image for the application
// 4) Add it to the AppList panel.
// 5) Set the event handler for each ImageButton, so when clicking it the associated 
//    application will run calling the web service
ApplicationItemEx[] items = proxy.GetApplicationsByCredentialsEx
    (credentials, Request.UserHostName,
Request.UserHostAddress, new  string[] { "icon","icon-info"}, new string[]{ "all" },
new string[] { "all"});

//loop for each published application
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
//create the ImageButton
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton app = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton();

//set the Image URL to the created image
app.ImageUrl = createIcon(items[i].InternalName,items[i].Icon);

//set the ToolTip to the name of the published application
app.ToolTip = items[i].InternalName;

//add the ImageButton to the AppList panel
AppList.Controls.Add(app);

//set the event handler for the ImageButton.
app.Click += new
System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.OnApplicationClicked);
```